# Override an Array value on Function call

Tags: php

I am using CodeIgnitor and I have a class with an array defined that has default settings but I want to be able to call one of the functions and replace one or more of the Array values, like this:

In a Model I have:

```
class Search {
    var $items = array("limit" => 10, "query"=>"foobars");

    function dosearch($items) {
        ...
   }

}
```

then call it from a Controller...

```
$this->load->model('search_model');
$items = array("limit"=>100);
$this->search_model->dosearch($items);
```

To be clear I just want to override some of the Models Class Array values and leave the rest as they are.

How can I best do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I worked out a really elegant solution that works for CodeIgnitor.

Create a config file, let's call it defaultdata.php and add your default data.

```
$config['searchData'] = array("limit"=>10, "query"=>"foobar");
```

then in your Controller add:

```
$this->config->load('defaultdata');
$this->load->model('dostuff_model');

$temp = $this->config->item('searchData');

$temp["limit"] = 100;
$data = $this->dostuff_model->search($temp);
...
```

and then you have the full array modified for this call ready to go! BOOM!!!!!

Thanks for your replies above guys, it helped me think this through.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

Extend your method implementation like this:

```
class Search {
    var $items = array("limit" => 10, "query"=>"foobars");

    function dosearch($override=array()) {
        // maybe first some general plausibility checks inside $override...
        if ( ! is_array($override) )
            return FALSE; // better to throw an exception here!
        // make a copy of $this->items you can modify:
        $innerItems = $this->items;
        // then use values inside $override
        foreach ($override as $key=>value) {
            // then some specialized plausibility checks, for example: 
            if ( ! in_array($key, array('limit','query') )
                continue;
            // is 'limit' a valid integer inside the range ]0,100]?
            if ( ('limit'==$key) && (0<(int)$value) && (100>=(int)$value) )
                $value=(int)$value;
            else 
                continue;
            // all fine, use override value
            $innerItems[$key] = $value;
        }
        // now do whatever you want with $innerItems
        // ...
   }    
}
```

Then you can do this at runtime:

```
$this->load->model('search_model');
$items = array("limit"=>100);
$this->search_model->dosearch($items);
```

Note that I did not test this, just wrote it down. I hope there is no minor typo left in it ;-)

Comment: I had thought about scanning the two arrays and check for Keys that match but I was hoping their was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can also use phps `array_merge()` function, if that is what you mean by "more elegant". But I learned not to do that, since it does not really allow plausibility checks the way I hinted at. And believe me: you _do_ want to implement such checks...

Comment: I understand what you are saying but wondered if there was a way to be able to let the Method Function know it was the same Array I was wanting to override.  I could use codeIgnitors $config but that would then replace the values for future use, which I do not want.

Comment: No sorry, nothing springs to my mind in that direction. You might think of moving the "overriding" how you call it from the method into the constructor or a separate method to take advantage of a centralization and abstraction. But I do not see a way to get around handling the arrays contents by means of a loop. And the clear disadvantage of such a generalized approach is that you have to implement the checks more abstract, which makes things complex again. In the end this is the difference between what a simple scripting engine is meant for and what a more advanced language can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the `$this->items` array with a new one or just change a key's value? In your example you're changing the whole array. If you wanna just change just one key, then do this `$this->items['limit'] = 100`.

Comment: The array will be quite large with many default values.  All I want to do is to call the function and override some of them.

So the default for "limit" will be 10 but I may want it to be overridden with 100 with the rest of hte values remaining the same.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Well then simply instantiate the object like `$search = new Search; $search->items['limit'] = 100;`. Of course that will only work if your `$items` variable is `public`.